# Why is the integer not incremented in this code?

Tags: c

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here to not get 11 as my output?

```
void foo {
    int *n = malloc(sizeof(int)); 
    *n = 10; 
    n++;
    printf("%d", *n)
}
```

Comment: you're also leaking the pointer.

Comment: @Stephen, not only leaking the pointer but doing it in a sort of interesting way. :)

Comment: Well, `n++` *is* defined as it's just past the end of an allocated object, so you could do `n--` and get the pointer back.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`n++` increments the pointer `n`, not the integer pointed to by `n`.  To increment the integer, you need to dereference the pointer and then increment the result of that:

```
(*n)++;
```

Comment: Suggest you change the wording slightly: "To dereference the integer" -> "To increment the integer"

Comment: @Matt:  Yes; I just saw that.  There must have been a bus error between my brain and fingers.  :-)  Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

If we call the malloc'ed variable `x`, then your program does this:

```
                                      n     x
int *n = malloc(sizeof(int));        &x     ?
*n = 10;                             &x    10
n++;                                &x+1   10
```

You want to do this:

```
                                      n     x
int *n = malloc(sizeof(int));        &x     ?
*n = 10;                             &x    10
(*n)++;                              &x    11
```

Comment: `++` has higher precedence than the unary `*`, so parentheses are needed in order to perform the dereference before the increment.

Comment: @James: K&R says the same precedence, but associativity right-to-left, so parentheses still needed.

Comment: @dmckee:  The postfix `++` has higher precedence than both the prefix `++` and unary `*` (the prefix `++` and unary `*` have the same precedence, as you say).

Comment: @James: Conceded, but it's not it the text, I had to go tothe appendix to find it.

Comment: @dmckee:  Ah; I don't have a copy of K&R here at home.  I typically just refer to the C99 PDF.

Answer (score 2):

You set n[0] to 10, and then you print n[1].  malloc() does not initialize the memory that it gives you, so what gets printed is unpredictable - it's whatever garbage happened to be in n[1].

Comment: Except, of course, that there is no `n[1]`, so you are reading from beyond the end of the allocated memory, the behavior of which is undefined.

Comment: Absolutely right!  I hadn't noticed that he used malloc to allocate a single int.

Answer (score 2):

You can get 11 as your output with this code:

```
void foo {
    int *n = malloc(sizeof(int)); 
    *n = 10; 
    (*n)++; 
    printf("%d", *n)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

n++ moves the pointer sizeof(int) bytes forward.